# Problem regarding summation of the Legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to calculate the following: $$\sum_{a = 1}^{p - 1}\left(\frac ap\right)$$ The value given for $p$ is fairly large and I can't individually calculate the symbol for all the numbers. However, I don't know how to go about calculating the solution. Can anyone help with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $p$ be an odd prime. The number of quadratic residues of $p$ is the same as the number of quadratic non-residues.

Comment: So basically, the number of quadratic residues and quadratic non-residues being the same means that the summation will be zero?

Comment: @Paradox101 You seem uncertain.  Why don't you try some small values of $p$ to convince yourself?

Comment: @Paradox101: Yes, equal number of $1$'s and $-1$'s, sum $0$.

Comment: @ErickWong I made a mistake in calculating the values which is why I was uncertain.

Comment: Ah, kind of like the Moebius function $\mu(n)$.